# xslt 2.0 check if at least one attribute value equals values specified in variable

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a variable that contains two values, e.g. `one two`

I have elements that have an attribute that has one of the values, none of these values or one of these values and other values, e.g.

```
<elem att="one"/>
<elem att="two"/>
<elem att="one somethingelse"/>
<elem att="two somethingelse somemore"/>
```

When I do this:

`<xsl:if test="@att = $variable"></xsl:if>` it is true if the attribute contains one of the values contained in the variable.

But it should also be true if the attribute value contains one of the values and then maybe some more, e.g. the last two `elem` elements.

How can I do that? Do I need to iterate over each attribute value separately?

So to make it clear: With my code, the test is only true for the first two `elem` elements but not for the last two. I nedd to check if at least one of the attribute values matches one of the values in the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your variable is a sequence of strings I would tokenize the attribute value and compare, i.e. `<xsl:if test="$variable = tokenize(@att, '\s+')">...</xsl:if>`.

Comment: worked perfectly, thanks a lot! But why do I have to tokenize it? How does the comparison work exactly?

Comment: `$sequence1 = $sequence2` is true if at least on item in `$sequence1` is equal to at least one item in `$sequence2`. Your attribute value is a single string that the `tokenize(@att, '\s+')` call converts into a sequence of strings. See http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-general-comparisons for the spec details on `=`.